# Finding missing function definitions

Tags: c, code-analysis

I have a large set of C source files that make up a fairly well architected system.  Now I've been tasked with cutting away a significant part of the system and replace it by stubs.  In order to estimate the work I'd like to find all functions definitions that are missing after the cutting away.  Is there some nice and effective way of doing this?

I've thought and come up with three ways

1. Compile the remaining parts and capture the link errors.
2. Compile and run `nm` on the object files, and taking the difference between `{functions marked 'U'}` and `{functions marked 'T'}`.
3. Use something like [pycparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycparser) to write a tool that catches the undefined functions.

Any better suggestions on how it can be done?

Comment: I'd probably go with (1) myself. Unless this is something you're going to be doing repeatedly, it isn't worth a huge investment in tool development and automation. In an IDE like Eclipse, I'd just excise the subsystem and then let Eclipse tell me what the rest of the code is actively looking for.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Eclipse, what do you mean by "excise the subsystem"?

Comment: "excise the subsystem" -- sorry, fancy way of saying "remove the code you no longer want." I'm suggesting Eclipse just because it provides a nice centralized view of error messages from an entire project, which might make going through the "not found" list a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

Check out tools like ctags/etags, or cscope. Particularly the last helps navigating large code bases.

Comment: Those are indeed good tools for navigating, but how can they help me find declared-and-used-but-not-defined functions?